# sum in closed form $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1\cdot 5}{3\cdot 7}+\frac{1\cdot 5\cdot 9}{3\cdot 7 \cdot 11}+...............$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Calculation of the given sum  in closed form $\displaystyle \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1\cdot 5}{3\cdot 7}+\frac{1\cdot 5\cdot 9}{3\cdot 7 \cdot 11}+...............$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write the given infinite series as $\displaystyle 1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1\cdot 5}{3\cdot 7}+\frac{1\cdot 5\cdot 9}{3\cdot 7 \cdot 11}+...............+(-1)$

Now $\displaystyle 1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1\cdot 5}{3\cdot 7}+\frac{1\cdot 5\cdot 9}{3\cdot 7 \cdot 11}+............... = (1+x)^n = 1+nx+\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot x^2}{2!}+.........$

we get $\displaystyle nx = \frac{1}{3}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot x^2}{2!} = \frac{1\cdot 5}{3\cdot 7}$

Is My process is right or not , if not how can i solve it

Help Required.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The series does not converge. You can use the comparison test against the divergent series $$\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{11} + ...$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

The serie ${\cal S}$ can be written as:
$$
{\cal S} = {1 \over 3}\braces{1 + {5 \over 7}\bracks{1 + {9 \over 11}
\pars{1 + \braces{1 + {13 \over 15}\bracks{1 + \cdots}}}}}
$$
Let's define
$\ds{%
{\cal S}_{n}
\equiv
{4n + 1 \over 4n + 3}
\bracks{1 + {4n + 5 \over 4n + 7}\pars{1 + \cdots}}}$ such that ${\cal S} = {\cal S}_{0}$ and
$\ds{%
{\cal S}_{n}
= 
{4n + 1 \over 4n + 3}\pars{1 + {\cal S}_{n + 1}}
}$:

$$
{\cal S}_{n + 1} = {4n + 3 \over 4n + 1}\,{\cal S}_{n} - 1
$$

Then, it diverges. See $\color{#8888ff}{\tt \mbox{@tfw can't into math}}$ answer.